# python in terminal - how to get current colour?

Tags: python, colors, terminal

I have read a couple of URLs about setting colour in terminal. But after a colour change a while later I'd like to reset into previous colour. How can I get current colour ?
(I'd like to avoid third party libraries and use only batteries included ;-))
Especially (from [(python) colour printing with decorator in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195877/python-colour-printing-with-decorator-in-a-function) ):

```
import sys
green = '\033[01;32m'
red = '\033[01;31m'

... remember current colours here ...
sys.stdout.write(green+"Hello ")
sys.stderr.write(red+"world!")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return default color the same way you colorize your texts:

```
native = '\033[m'
sys.stdout.write(native)
```

Thus temporary coloring may be achieved with

```
print green + 'Hello' + native
```

Comment: It does not work, it sets the terminal to the default color, not the color that terminal was in prior to changing the color inside python.